# Formulate a simple logarithmic equation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math

How can I formulate the following idea?

I have *p* (parameter). I want to know how many times I need to divide it by 2 until the result of the division is around *d*.

For example, let *p* = 400 and *d* = 25. I need to divide it 4 times by 2 to get *d* ~ 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivial: d*2^n = p, hence n = log(p/d)/log(2). Then just round up n in the direction you want.